# Get most frequent word in a list

Tags: python

I have a list of names that is not normalized, for example:

```
'one Bull', 'A Horse', 'Horse', 'Dog', 'Black dog', 'Brown dog', 'Bird', 'I'm a horse', 'I'm not a dog'
```

What I'm trying to get is a list of most common values, this would be easy using SQL if the data where clean, but having not normalized data I don't know how could I get a similar list like this:

```
'Dog' - 4
'Horse' - 3
'A' - 3
...
```

I've seen that Python has a Counter module that could be helpful, but it would count a String as one `"One bull"` , and not as a mix of words `"One", "Bull".`

Maybe splitting the strings before?

Comment: modify the initial list using `split` like `x = [y.split() for y in list]` then flatten it and then `count`.

Answer (score 4):

You can split the items in the list into separate words and covert the first letters to uppercase using [`str.capitalize`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize) before counting with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

lst= ['one Bull', 'A Horse', 'Horse', 'Dog', 'Black dog', 'Brown dog', 'Bird', 'I\'m a horse', 'I\'m not a dog']
c = Counter(i.capitalize() for x in lst for i in x.split())
print(c)
# Counter({'Dog': 4, 'Horse': 3, 'A': 3, "I'm": 2, 'Black': 1, 'Brown': 1, 'Bull': 1, 'Not': 1, 'One': 1, 'Bird': 1})
```

And then use the counter object's [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) to get your required number of most common items:

```
print(c.most_common(3))
# [('Dog', 4), ('Horse', 3), ('A', 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write some Python code to normalize the given list first. After that you can do a count, there is plenty of existing code for counting.

Another try, closely related to my first suggestion: make sure you know which animals could appear and make sure you have a list of them, like `animals = ['dog', 'horse', 'bird', bull']`. Now iterate over the `animals` and count how many times each animal occurs. You might want to do a lowercase on the string.